# Execute useEffect() only on specific setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback, use-effect

I am using a hook component and several state variables. I have read about using `useEffect()` with params to get a kind of callback after updating a state. Example:

```
export const hookComponent = () => {
    const [var, setVar] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        //do things
    }, [var])
}
```

In this example, `useEffect()` would be executed on every `setVar()` call. In my case, I do not want to execute `useEffect()` everytime, but only on specific occasions.
I would like to give the `setVar()` some kind of information which I can use in `useEffect()` like `setVar(newValue, true)`.

Note: I do not want to store this information in var.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: in your `useEffect` just check if `var === desiredValue` then `//do things`

Comment: In my use case it is not only about the value, but also about the user action. setState does not return a Promise which I could wait for on the relevant instances after a set. Or is there a way to wait for a setState to complete?

Comment: how do you this action has been taken ? this information has to be captured somewhere.

Comment: I have several occasions where setState is called, but want this action only on some of them. The relevant would get that information. E.g. as an additional parameter

Comment: It seems like the best way to approach this is to have another state `newVar` that gets updated where you would like your `useEffect` to trigger and the dependencies of that would be `newVar` and not your `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nizar said, simple conditional check on 'var' in useEffect

If expensive calc you can

```
const expensiveValue = useMemo(() => {
    // other logic here if needed
    // could even be simple return var=='x'?true:false, although this would be easier to do in the useEffect hook?
    return computeExpensiveValue(var);
},[var]);

useEffect(() => {
    //do things
    //expensiveValue only changes when you want it to from the memo
}, [expensiveValue])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sambomartin and Nizar for your input.

For everyone looking for an answer:
After some further research I found 3 possible solutions:

1. Use a class component. If you really are dependent on that state update to be completed switch to a class component, which allows you to give the `setState()` a callback as a second param.
2. Use the `useRef` hook to determine where your state update is comming from. You can use this information in the `useEffect()` method.
3. Get independent from the state. I used this solution and externalized my callback function with the drawback of giving it every parameter on every call, although they are present in the component the states are saved.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **the useEffect only triggers if the dependency value changes**, not simply by executing setValue.

I offer you three solutions, the first one, close to what you want but without using useEffect hook, the second one is an extension of the first one, that may be required if you need control over the previous state, and the third, more general, like comments say, though **it won't be triggered if the state is the same, even if you execute setValue**.

1. First solution: Wrap your set value with another function that definitely controls what may happen after or before the new state:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const handleChangeSetState = (nextState, flag) => {
    if (flag) {
      specialUseCaseCb();
    }
    setState(nextState);
  };

  return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
}
```

2. Second solution: Wrap your set value with another function, like in the solution 1, and ask for the previous or next state within setState inner callback:

```
export default function MyComponent2() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const handleChangeSetState = (increment, flag) =>
    setState((prevState) => {
      const nextState = prevState + increment;
      // you may need prevState or nextState for checking your use case
      if (flag) {
        specialUseCaseCb();
      }
      return nextState;
    });

  return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
}
```

3. Third solution: use useEffect hook **to follow changes**, remember though that setState won't re-trigger useEffect hook if the state is the same:

```
export default function MyComponent3() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  // notice that this will only be triggered if state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state !== "my-special-use-case") return;
    specialUseCaseCb();
  }, [state]);

  return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first solution is what I though of on my first attempt. But in my case I want to wait for the updated state and then execute my callback. If I got this right, that is not the case in your example, right?

Comment: In the third example you will wait for state to be updated to execute your callback.

Comment: But for the content of the state is used to decide wether to execute my callback or not. I did not want to make changes to the structure of the state